# Read image file from server

Tags: c#, winforms, connect

I have to display image in form in my application,
the image in a shared directory for every one in the server

If I attempt to read the image by:

```
fullImagePath = Path.Combine(@"\\serverIP\IMG_IN_server", imageFileName);
byte[] img = File.ReadAllBytes(fullImagePath);
```

but I get error "Access to the path is denied"

edit:
can I use the user and the password to connect to avoid this problem ?

Comment: Check [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271701/reading-image-from-web-server-in-c-sharp-proxy/1272126#1272126) given to [Reading Image from Web Server in C# [proxy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271701/reading-image-from-web-server-in-c-sharp-proxy/). It reads image data into

Comment: there's nothing wrong with the code you've posted, it just sounds like the path you specified is wrong

Comment: I verified the path I correct the error but Now I got "Access to the path is denied."

Comment: Check that your application has read access to that location. This is not necessarily the same as **you** having read access.

Comment: can I use the user and the password to connect to avoid this problem ?

Comment: can access to this file from windows Explorer ? make sure this isn't security problem!

Comment: @Rev: No I can't access to this file by explorer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as Result your test:

I can Say your problem is *`normal security configuration`*. In order to have access that file you need share that **`file with allow security permission`**.

Your Code is right Just go for security permission.