# Save map image from coordinates

Tags: .net, google-maps, dictionary

I need to to do the following thing: I have a list of coordinates which delimitates a map area. With those coordinates, I need to visualize that area with a map provider (example: google maps, bing, et c) and save the obtained image to a file.

I'm developing a c# application in .net 2.0 framework, exist a library or calls which can help me to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to use Google Static Maps API. Due to the source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Overview

> The Google Static Maps API returns an image (either GIF, PNG or JPEG)
>   in response to an HTTP request via a URL. For each request, you can
>   specify the location of the map, the size of the image, the zoom
>   level, the type of map, and the placement of optional markers at
>   locations on the map. You can additionally label your markers using
>   alphanumeric characters.
>
> A Static Maps API image is embedded within an  tag's src
>   attribute, or its equivalent in other programming languages.

When you get img source you can manipulate within it throw javascript (for getting: [Get image data in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript)  and for saving: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-save-drawing-as-an-image/) or using server code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1272126/157666